# AngularJS + RequireJS application never runs the controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, amd

**EDIT** As far as I understood through further research AngularJS isn't capable of injecting that controller code the way I wanted it to do. Anyway, I'm still interested in why exactly doesn't it work and how should it be done.

I've been trying to create my own AngularJS + RequireJS project seed and I've run into issues with app modules loading (I see them in the network inspector) but never actually executing.
So I've stripped down the app to just the AngularJS library with basic dependencies handled through in RequireJS and I've noticed that the app loads all of the files and modules properly but the top level application module controller (and now the only module in the app itself) that I'm bootstrapping onto the document never executes. Using ng-inspector I've come to a conclusion that there's also no controller scope defined.
There are no errors whatsoever in the console and what I can confirm is that app bootstraps properly and loads all of the modules but the appController is never executed.

Here's the code of the appBootstrap.js:

```
//requirejs config
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    paths: {
        'lib' : 'scripts/lib/',
        'angular' : 'vendor/angular/angular.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});
//the actual app bootstrapping
require(['lib/appVendorLibs'], function(){
    require([
        'lib/appModule'
    ], function(appModule) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, [appModule.name]);
    });
});
```

Here's the appVendorLibs.js:

```
define([
    'angular'
], function() {});
```

And here's the barebones appModule.js that I've come up with in order to test the controller execution that fails:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'lib/appController'
], function(angular, appController) {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('appController', appController);
    return app;
});
```

Here's the appController.js:

```
define([], function() {
    var appController = function($scope, $rootScope){
        $rootScope.aTestVar = "OK";
        $scope.testObject = {};
        $scope.testObject.text = "OK";
        console.log("OK");
    };

    return ['$scope', '$rootScope', appController];
});
```

That `console.log()` call is never occurs nor do those lines referencing the `$rootScope` and `$scope` do anything.
Also, I've got `ng-bind` in my `index.html` that should be displaying the `testObject.text` variable but that never happens.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css"/>
        <title>AngularJS Module Loading Seed</title>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Main Content Container -->
       <p ng-bind="testObject.text"></p>
       <script src="/vendor/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/scripts/lib/appBootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: The HTML you show in your last snippet is incorrect. You have a `</div>` but no corresponding opening tag. I don't recall how browsers fix that problem but sometimes incorrect HTML can result in surprises. Also, did you try waiting until the document is ready before bootstrapping your application (`angular.element(document).ready(....`)?

Comment: That div was a typo while I was trying to paste the code here, it isn't present in the app. Also, I did try checking if document was ready prior to bootstrapping but that didn't help.